# Problem installing Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM on OSX 10.4

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I successfully installed Ruby 1.8.7 with RVM on OS 10.4. However, when I try to install 1.9.2,
I get the following error:
make: *** [libruby.1.9.1.dylib] Error 1

Installation:

```
[qm]$ rvm install 1.9.2  
/Users/qm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
%  
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching %  
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your connection...%  
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p136 to /Users/qm/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%  
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracted to /Users/qm/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%  
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #configuring %  
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #compiling %  
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/qm/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/make.log%  
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.%
```

The end of the /Users/qm/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/make.log:

```
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/powerpc-darwin8.11.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o prelude.o -c prelude.c  
ar rcu libruby.1.9.1-static.a dln.o encoding.o version.o array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o complex.o dir.o dln_find.o enum.o enumerator.o error.o eval.o load.o proc.o file.o gc.o hash.o inits.o io.o marshal.o math.o node.o numeric.o object.o pack.o parse.o process.o random.o range.o rational.o re.o regcomp.o regenc.o regerror.o regexec.o regparse.o regsyntax.o ruby.o safe.o signal.o sprintf.o st.o strftime.o string.o struct.o time.o transcode.o util.o variable.o compile.o debug.o iseq.o vm.o vm_dump.o thread.o cont.o ascii.o us_ascii.o unicode.o utf_8.o newline.o alloca.o prelude.o dmyext.o  
gcc -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace -install_name /Users/qm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib -current_version 1.9.1 -compatibility_version 1.9.1  -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend    dln.o encoding.o version.o array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o complex.o dir.o dln_find.o enum.o enumerator.o error.o eval.o load.o proc.o file.o gc.o hash.o inits.o io.o marshal.o math.o node.o numeric.o object.o pack.o parse.o process.o random.o range.o rational.o re.o regcomp.o regenc.o regerror.o regexec.o regparse.o regsyntax.o ruby.o safe.o signal.o sprintf.o st.o strftime.o string.o struct.o time.o transcode.o util.o variable.o compile.o debug.o iseq.o vm.o vm_dump.o thread.o cont.o ascii.o us_ascii.o unicode.o utf_8.o newline.o alloca.o prelude.o dmyext.o  -o libruby.1.9.1.dylib  
ld: flag: -undefined dynamic_lookup can't be used with MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET environment variable set to: 10.1  
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin8/4.0.1/libtool: internal link edit command failed  
make: *** [libruby.1.9.1.dylib] Error 1
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Comment: There is more than likely more to that error than the final line. Please show us the steps you are using to get that error.

Comment: Could you please show us the contents of the /Users/qm/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/make.log file?

Comment: dvyjones, added the end of the logfile. I am not sure what  is the best way to post the entire log file here.

Answer (score 2):

Voilà! Examining once again my previous make.log file for errors I found that probably there was a problem w readline, so I combined few tips, first from noodl's to set up the env var and second from RVM website http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/ to update the readline and use it during rvm ruby 1.9.2 install.

So, before my first post today in this thread I did:

```
$ rvm package install readline
```

to get the latest readline library.

What I did afterwards is as follows:

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
Removing /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136...%
it seems that /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 is already non existent.%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 aliases...%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 wrappers...%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 environments...%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 binaries...%
$ MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4 rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
/Users/mdziurla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p136 to /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracted to /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #configuring %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #compiling %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #installing %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - updating #rubygems for /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - updating #rubygems for /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem).%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/mdziurla/.rvm/gemsets/)%
Install of ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #complete %
```

And all is set and ready.

```
$ rvm 1.9.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [powerpc-darwin8.11.0]
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Install [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) first - Tiger has a few problems when it comes to Ruby Dev and Brew will help fix them. Once installed just go..

```
brew install ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem on Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger (PPC) trying to install ruby 1.9.2. I successfully compiled and installed ruby 1.9.1 thru RVM, but neither 1.9.2 nor 1.8.7 have the same problem using RVM. I did the following steps to get this error.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0) [powerpc-darwin8.11.0]
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.2.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
$ rvm install 1.9.2
/Users/mdziurla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p136 to /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracted to /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #configuring %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #compiling %
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/make.log%
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.%
```

My make.log output you will find at:
http://www.pastie.org/1467180

Answer (score 0):

Have either of you tried just changing that env var?

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4 rvm install 1.9.2
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the tip by noodl from just few minutes ago I tried to set up the env var and got similar problem. Still ruby 1.9.2 is not installed. Underneath is what I did:

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
Removing /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136...%
it seems that /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 is already non existent.%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 aliases...%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 wrappers...%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 environments...%
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p136 binaries...%
$ MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4 rvm install 1.9.2
/Users/mdziurla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p136 to /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracted to /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136%
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #configuring %
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #compiling %
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/mdziurla/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/make.log%
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.%
```

The make.log output you can find at:
http://www.pastie.org/1467265