# Fail to install ruby 1.9.2 in RVM on OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-yosemite

Ok guys, I already tried to:

- Reinstall RVM;
- Update XCode to 6.1;
- Install command_line_tools_for_osx_10.10_for_xcode_6.1.dmg;

Nothing works for me!

When I run `rvm install ruby-1.9.2` I got this error:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p330.
It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it for your system only.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
/Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/scripts/functions/build: line 110: 33084 Segmentation fault: 11  ${compiler} "$@" 2>&1
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p330, this may take a while depending on your connection...
######################################################################## 100.0%
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p330 to /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p330....
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #applying patch /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #applying patch /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #configuring.
Error running 'env CFLAGS=-O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib ./configure --prefix=/Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/log/1413833087_ruby-1.9.2-p330/configure.log
[2014-10-20 17:24:50] ./configure
current path: /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p330
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/brunnosantos/dotfiles/powerline/scripts:/usr/local/bin:/Users/brunnosantos/.azk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/brunnosantos/bin:/Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/bin:/Users/brunnosantos/go/bin:/usr/local/smlnj/bin    
command(10): env CFLAGS=-O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib ./configure --prefix=/Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p330':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

When I tried `rvm install ruby-1.9.2 --with-gcc=clang` I got:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.2-p330..
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: found user selected compiler 'clang', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p330, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p330 to /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p330....
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #applying patch /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #applying patch /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #configuring..........................................
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.9.2-p330 - #compiling...........................................................................................................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/log/1413833194_ruby-1.9.2-p330/make.log
#define UNINITIALIZED_VAR(x) x = x
                                 ^
4 warnings generated.
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o cont.o -c cont.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o ascii.o -c ./enc/ascii.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o us_ascii.o -c ./enc/us_ascii.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o unicode.o -c ./enc/unicode.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o utf_8.o -c ./enc/utf_8.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o newline.o -c newline.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o dmyext.o -c dmyext.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -L. -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend   main.o dmydln.o dmyencoding.o dmyversion.o miniprelude.o array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o complex.o dir.o dln_find.o enum.o enumerator.o error.o eval.o load.o proc.o file.o gc.o hash.o inits.o io.o marshal.o math.o node.o numeric.o object.o pack.o parse.o process.o random.o range.o rational.o re.o regcomp.o regenc.o regerror.o regexec.o regparse.o regsyntax.o ruby.o safe.o signal.o sprintf.o st.o strftime.o string.o struct.o time.o transcode.o util.o variable.o compile.o debug.o iseq.o vm.o vm_dump.o thread.o cont.o ascii.o us_ascii.o unicode.o utf_8.o newline.o  dmyext.o -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  -o miniruby
miniruby(46919,0x7fff7a0cc300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fed53001a08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Full log file `/Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/log/1413833194_ruby-1.9.2-p330/make.log` can be viwed in: https://gist.github.com/squiter/b6c4280946454b6b7764

I installed 1.9.3 with `rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`, worked well, but no success with 1.9.2.

I don't know what I can try anymore....

Comment: I suspect this is a problem in the Ruby 1.9.2 codebase itself.  Are you able to install 1.9.3 without problems?

Comment: Yes @Donovan, I already tried with 1.9.3... same errors.

Comment: Hmm... Unfortunately, I'm unable to replicate the problem locally as 1.9.3 installs cleanly for me (using rbenv and ruby-build). Only thing that springs to mind is to try closing and reopening your terminal window.  Sometimes after installing packages you need to reload your shell env.

Comment: Also, can you post what's in `/Users/brunnosantos/.rvm/log/1413833194_ruby-1.9.2-p330/make.log` for us?

Comment: Could this be a readline issue? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567830/problem-installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-on-osx-10-4

Comment: You're trying to install a deprecated Ruby on a newly released OS. I think it'd be good to be patient and maybe they will release 1.9.3 compiled on OSX 10.10.

Comment: @Donovan https://gist.github.com/squiter/b6c4280946454b6b7764

Comment: @thohl I can't run `rvm package install readline`.. that command doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: @Donovan I installed `rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`! Its worked, but 1.9.2 still failing

Comment: As I said before, I suspect a problem in the 1.9.2 codebase and since 1.9.3 is the latest in the 1.9 series, I doubt it will be fixed.  Is there some reason you cannot use 1.9.3?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?

`export CC=/usr/bin/gcc`

and then trying to install?

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported known problem in Ruby on OSX depending on your C compiler version.
You might find a solution here: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/648

Answer (score 0):

I found that reinstalling gcc4.2 (via homebrew, in my case: 'brew install gcc42') and then using that clang compiler when installing older rubies allows the installation to succeed.

Comment: I can't find gcc42, the versions of gcc that are available in homebrew are apple-gcc42, gcc, gcc43, gcc44, gcc45, gcc46, gcc47l, gcc48, gcc49, llvm-gcc28. I tryed to install with apple-gcc42 but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the ruby 2.2.0 version installed and I try to install the -v 1.9.2 and I do this previously recommended and when I try to install ruby I have his fail:
```
$ rvm install ruby -v '1.9.2'
Already installed ruby-2.2.0.
To reinstall use:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.0
```

```
Anyone can Help me, the problem is the new version of Mac OS X Yosemite( I'm so bad about the updating of this OS I has so many errors on drivers(wi-fi, bluetooth, etc...)

Comment: Try this: `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc`